# Changing data type of column in a table from TEXT to LVARCHAR(10000)

Tags: sql, database, informix

I want to change/modify the data type `TEXT` of column `batch_calc_query` in a table `d_etl_queries` to `LVARCHAR(10000)`. I am doing this by executing the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE d_etl_queries MODIFY (batch_calc_query LVARCHAR(10000));
```

But, it gives me the following error:

```
9633: ALTER TABLE can not modify column (batch_calc_query) type.  Need a cast from the current type
```

Is there any way I can avoid this error?

Comment: Remove the parentheses.

Comment: Same error facing

Comment: Which Informix version are you using? What is the original type of the column you want to modify?

Comment: Informix version is 2.21 and original data type of column is TYPE which is also mentioned in the problem title

Comment: That makes no sense for me. Not even sure if there was an Informix version 2.21 . What does the following query return for you:  `SELECT DBINFO( 'version', 'full' ) FROM systables WHERE tabid = 1;` ? And the only data type TYPE that I am aware of in Informix is an `OPAQUE TYPE` and that means it is a user custom type and there will not exist any cast from that custom type into LVARCHAR.

Comment: @LuísMarques — I agree that the version 2.21 is not and never was a valid Informix (server) version, even going back to the days of 1985-90.  It might be a valid version number for some client API, but I'm not sure which.  I think that TYPE in the comment by the OP (and in the question body) is a typo for TEXT, which is mentioned in the question title (but the question text should always stand on its own and make sense, even if the title is changed to "How extraordinary is Stack Overflow" or something equally tangential).  (I've edited the question body to reference TEXT instead of TYPE.)

Answer (score 3):

Running the two statements:

```
CREATE TABLE blob_to_lvarchar(s SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, b TEXT IN TABLE);
ALTER TABLE blob_to_lvarchar MODIFY b LVARCHAR(10000);
```

generates the advertised error.  There isn't an easy way around that — you'd have to add a cast to the system (CREATE CAST) backed up with the appropriate C function to make the change.

You are going to need to unload the table, drop it, recreate it with the correct column type, and reload the table.